# Problem while animating boxes using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

On my webpage, I have a few boxes one below the other, on the right side. Each box has a '+' and '-' button which maximizes/minimizes to the specified size, similar to that in portlets. But, for some reason, it is not working as it is suppose to. 
Here is the code for '-' button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($modules);$i++) : ?>        
    $( "#minusbtn<?=$modules[$i]["title"]?>").click(
    function() {
        $( "#effect<?=$modules[$i]  ["title"]?>").animate({                 
height: 35,
}, "slow" );
    <?php $count=0; $top=0; ?>  
    <?php for($j=$i;$j<count($modules);$j++): ?>
    <?php if($i==$j) continue; ?>
        $( "#effect<?=$modules[$j]["title"]?>" ).animate({
        top: <?=($top)?>,
        }, "slow" );
    <?php $count++; $top = (210*$count); ?> 
    <?php endfor; ?>
    });
```

Please help!

Comment: Do you have a live example of this somewhere?

Comment: @Juhana: I am sorry, I dint quite get that. I am new to JavaScript. But I think, the part of the code that I have posted here is all that matters.

Comment: @Andrew: I want it to work something like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets
When one box is minimized/maximized, the boxes below it should change the positions accordingly.

Comment: The code that you posted is PHP that generates JavaScript. It's very hard if not impossible to read. When you go to the page with the browser, select "view source", go to the place where that piece of JavaScript is and copy-paste it here.

Comment: rahul_desai: you're mixing PHP with JavaScript. The "generated JavaScript" mentioned by @Juhana is the JavaScript that is inserted in the final HTML generated by PHP.

Comment: @Juhana and Marco: 

    $( "#minusbtnPATIENT" ).click(
    function() {
        $( "#effectPATIENT" ).animate({     
        height: 35, },"slow");          $( "#effectSCHEDULER" ).animate({
        top: 0,
        }, "slow" );    
                 $( "#effectINBOX" ).animate({
        top: 210,
        }, "slow" );   
                    $( "#effectNOTES" ).animate({
        top: 420,
        }, "slow" );    
                    $( "#effectLAB" ).animate({
        top: 630,
        }, "slow" );    
           $( "#effectBILLING" ).animate({
        top: 840,
        }, "slow" );  
    });

Comment: I would update the question with that code, it'll be easier to read that way.

Comment: The next question: what does "it is not working as it is suppose to" mean? What does it do? Or does it not do anything?

Comment: @Juhana: The problem with this code is, when I click on '-' button, the box blow it completely covers/overlaps the box that I clicked on. As you can notice, the problem is with the logic. I am not getting what I should put in the position parameter '$top'.

Answer (score 1):

All it is that makes the boxes is this:

```
$( ".portlet-header" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
});
```

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ndHK4/.

Comment: Sorry I am not using portlets. And there is nothing like prtlet content in my code.

Comment: They don't need to be portlets, the classes can be whatever your want. The essence of this is that when you click on the header, the content inside will hide and the rest will move up.